# Sort dates for one week, one month, and one year with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which I'm sorting data with. Right now I'm sorting from newest to oldest and vice versa. Now, I want to sort it to get all the data from the previous week or previous month or previous year. Here is what I have now for some basic sorting:

```
rowsOne.sort(function(a, b) {

    var A = $(a).children("td").eq(1).text().toUpperCase();
    var B = $(b).children("td").eq(1).text().toUpperCase();

            var unixA = new Date(A);
            var unixB = new Date(B);

    if(unixA < unixB) { 
        return -1;
    }

    if(unixA > unixB) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;           
});
```

How can I change this to allow sorting by weeks, months or year?

**EDIT**
Sorry, I pasted in the wrong piece of code. This is the updated javascript.
And no, I cant show you the table itself - it contains information I cant make available.

**EDIT 2**
I need to clarify. I don't need to filter AFTER the table has been sorted. The option to select the data based on a past week, month or year is available in conjunction WITH also being able to sort the data from newest to oldest (or oldest to newest). I need the ability to get data from "last week", "last month" and "last year" independent from the actual sorting.

**EDIT 3** 
Anybody have any idea?

Comment: Are you using Unix timestamps? SQL timestamps? Formatted strings?

Comment: Can we see a sample of the table?

Comment: @Jamie I am just the javascript date object. I updated the code.

Comment: You are not just using the JS object, you are passing a string into the `Date` constructor. That is the question, what are you passing into the `Date` constructor?

Comment: I'm passing a string. It's in a format that Date() understands. I just need to show the rows in the table that are from "a week ago" or "year ago" or "month ago"

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about 2 different things. Your sort functionality is correct, but now you need a filter function.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

You can do the same selector for the filter, then determine whether it should be displayed based on whether your selected filter is week, month, or year.

Comment: I clarified what I needed in the question. I need the ability to get data from "last week", "last month" and "last year" independent from the actual sorting. The sorting code I posted is just the framework to get the data... So you still may be correct, yet I'm not sure how to filter anything down to a past week, month or year.